# Check the amount of blocks/groups an integer list is composed of

Tags: python, integer

Consider the following list:

```
alist = [18,5,22,6,38,43]
```

This list is composed of numbers ranging from 1 to 49. These 49 numbers are divided into 7 groups:

```
oneto49numbers = list(range(1, 50))
grouped = list(zip(*[iter(oneto49numbers)]*7))
```

How can I check the amount of different groups the numbers in alist come from? For alist, manually determined it would be like this:

```
18 from grouped[2]
5  from grouped[0]
22 from grouped[3]
6  from grouped[0]
38 from grouped[5]
43 from grouped[6]
```

So for **alist** this number would be 5, as the numbers of alist come from 5 different groups. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `len(set((x - 1) // 7 for x in alist))`

Comment: Is `grouped` sorted in that way, or is that just a random example of a grouping of integers? If it is sorted like that Dietrich is right, otherwise you have to use a nested loop to check for membership for each element (or sort things beforehand)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something along these lines:

```
import numpy as np

len(np.unique([[i for i, group in enumerate(grouped) if x in group] for x in alist]))
```

Which returns `5`.

If you wanted to use the information, `[[i for i, group in enumerate(grouped) if x in group] for x in alist]` would return the groups each element belongs to in order:

```
[[2], [0], [3], [0], [5], [6]]
```

and `len(np.unique(...` gives you the number of unique groups in that list of lists.

The only advantage I see to this sort of method as opposed to the `[(x - 1) // 7 for x in alist]` strategy outlined in other posts and in comments is that it would hold up for non-evenly sized groups.

Answer (score 1):

How do you know which of the groups you put each number into? You floordiv it by 7 and take that as group-number. Put all into a set (count each group once) and count the lenght of the set:

```
def findUsedGroups(groupSize,data):
    """Partitions 1-based number lists into groups of groupSize. 
       Returns amount of groups needed for a given data iterable."""
    return len(set ( (x-1)//groupSize for x in data))     

alist = [18,5,22,6,38,43]
print(findUsedGroups(7,alist))
```

Output:

```
5
```

Comment: @Aran-Fey Keen Eye - off by one on my part.Thanks for correcting me.